# How do I use Stimpaks and RadAways on Dwellers in the Wasteland?

Tags: fallout-shelter

So, in **Fallout Shelter**, whenever I send my Dwellers to the *Wasteland*, I give them five Stimpaks and five RadAways, but they never use them when they are injured/radiated. I don't know how to make my Dwellers use them. How do I do this?

Comment: Just some friendly advice, I would give them more Stimpaks and RadAways then 5 of them. Give them around 15 of them. ;)

Answer (score 15):

There is no way to force them to use them, they will just use them on their own until their stock you give them when you send them out goes away.

Nothing (that is in the game right now) can cause them to die in a single attack that they would not be able to heal from so no worries there. When they get up to the radiation amount a RadAway would heal then they will use one, then their health is low enough for a Stimpack to fill it up, they will use it.

A good ratio is 2 to 1 from Stimpacks to Radaway. I generally will send out my guys with 20 Stim Packs and 10 Rad Aways though they will often still return with a RadAway or two on them. I will also do 15 and 10 if I am low. Your residents will never need RadAway unless you run low on water so as long as that is ok do not fear sending more with your guys in the wastes.

Comment: I usually just max their inventory out (25). I make that many stimpack/Radaways back in ~20 min, and my vault can only store 35 of each.

Comment: Note that a dweller is immune to radiation at 12 endurance, and barely takes any at all at 10. A dweller with 10 endurance will use only use a couple radaway by the time they use 25 stimpacks.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you don't. They decide when to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use them. Your person will not die as long as you send radaways and stimpacks with them. Your person will use the power ups when they are low on health/water.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them I'm your traveler comes back without any left. Mine just did and his little speaking bubble said things like "I'm feeling nauseous". And I was able to give him a rad away and a stimpack.  He's good now.