# Can dwellers die before using all their Stimpaks while exploring?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The HP of one of my explorers is getting dangerously low. He still has 2 stimpaks (and is below level 10, so each use would heal alot). I wonder if he is 100% safe as long as he has stimpaks, or if he can be instagibbed (dying from a high damage hit even though he has healing items).

Comment: Are you sure he actually has stimpaks and not radaways?  Half is not "dangerously low".  He can obviously die if he doesn't have stimpaks.

Comment: In current version, I don't know, but it happenned to me long ago, low health, low level, low protection dweller against a high level random encounter. The fact it was a one off event, and so long ago, while I constantly have dweller outside, make me think it was a bug, and that *Yes*, your dweller will be fine.

Comment: with below-10 level, even with maximum number of stimpaks a dweller can carry, i doubt that he/she will go far enough to meet opponent that could drain the rest of his/her health point in one blow. but this is based on my limited experience only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Exploring wikia page](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Exploring):

> Outfits increase their statistics and ability to survive, weapons improve their chance to defeat enemies, **while Stimpaks and RadAway ensure that they can heal damage and remove any radiation they absorb.**

Also, from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224454/how-do-i-use-stimpaks-and-radaways-on-dwellers-in-the-wasteland),

> There is no way to force them to use them, **they will just use them on their own until their stock you give them when you send them out goes away.**

From these posts as well as personal experience, vault dwellers will not die before using *all* of the Stimpaks you send them to explore with.

Answer (score 1):

Stimpacks heal about 50% of a dweller's health, regardless of level or their maximum health.

While exploring, dwellers will use a stimpack whenever their health drops low enough to use it without wasting any. So, half health.

Therefore, in order to die before using all of their stimapacks, an exploring dweller would have to take more than half of their maximum health in one instance of damage, killing them before they had a chance to use a stimpack.

Considering how small each instance of damage suffered in the wasteland is, I believe that this is impossible, although I don't have hard numbers to Science! for you.

Source: experience playing the game, https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/4c4m46/everything_health/,

Comment: Possible, just very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it’s possible. It has never happened to my dwellers, until now.

As you can see from the screenshot, the dweller still has plenty Stimpaks and Radaway, but she still managed to die. When I revived her, she had her HP bar 100% full of radiation. See the last entries in the journal, too.

I have no idea why she didn’t use the Radaway when she had 24 units left.

[image: dead with supplies]

And she’s has pretty good SPECIAL too:

[image]